# Where to parse a large txt file ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a large txt file thar I want to parse in my web application. Earlier, I had the same application as a kind of desktop application, and I did the parsing one time during the Load, and briong the contents of file into memory.

Here in ASP.NET website, I am not sure if I should be doing this in Page_Load() since parsing a 13Mb text file would make this slow for the user everytime. What should I do to bring this one time into memory and then for all the users, the same in-memory parsed contents can be looked up?

Comment: What is the format of txt file? Is it XML, comma separated, tab separated? After parsing the txt file, you can place it in Application level cache to allow access to all ASPX pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your file is same for all the users you can put in cache provided by asp.net. If it is specific to user then session could be a place for it but that will acquire a lot of memory and make it almost devastating. This is how you can [Cache file in asp.net](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=331)

```
string fileContent = Cache["SampleFile"] as string;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileContent))
{
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(Server.MapPath("~/SampleFile.txt")))
   {
       fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
       Cache.Insert("SampleFile", fileContent, new System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency(Server.MapPath("~/SampleFile.txt")));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would load it in **global.asax** in the Application_Start event handler.  Then add it to the cache and retrieve as needed.

To decrease the likelihood of your data being dropped from the cache, you can specify that it is not removable:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(
    "mydatakey",        // key for retrieval
     MyDataObject,      
     null,              // cache dependencies
     DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),      // absolute expiration
     TimeSpan.FromDays(1),         // sliding expiration  
     System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable,       // priority
     new CacheItemRemovedCallback(MyHandleRemovedCallback)
);
```

For more detail this caching method data, see here on MSDN (Caching Application Data):  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Can you put in a bit more detail about putting it in cache, or point to some link where I can look how to do this? Thanks

Comment: `Application["MyKey"] = MyValue`.

Comment: @user1372448 added some more details on caching.  You can use UweKeim's suggestion; the only potential problem there is that your server may decide to dump your data from the cache more often than you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you MUST load a 13 mb text file into memory for a website then I would suggest using an Application variable you can set this in the Global.asax file, this will be available to all the users within the site.

Once the file is there it will remain until the application pool is unloaded from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Use Application["key"] = value. You need to cache this in the server and Application should do it like saving things in Session like Session["userid"] = something.